# Is it possible to prevent an AngularJS app to start during business hours?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to prevent an AngularJS app to start during business hours ?

Let's say that I do not want the app to be working between 8h and 18h. During this time, I want to display a page saying that the user must come back at `the time left`.

Comment: You can do it from the client but preferably from the server as d4rty mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

JavaScript allows to get date, and time using `Date` object. For example

```
var date = new Date(); // Will set date variable as current date object
console.log(new Date().getTime()) // Will print time (milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970)
```

You can further process the date using Moment JS library - http://momentjs.com/

Using Moment JS you can extract hour, and minute and set simple boolean variable in scope. Let's name it `businessHours`.

Then you can create two `div` elements with `ng-show`/`ng-hide` commands:

```
<div ng-hide='businessHours'>
   <!-- application -->
</div>

<div ng-show='businessHours'>
   <!-- error message saying that the user must come back at the time left -->
</div>
```

**BUT** keep in mind it's very easy to hack. If user simply change hour on his machine the application won't show error message. So this check should be moved to server side code. But it's not Angular matter anymore.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do it in the `run` part and `$state.go` to a specific template ? So that the application does not start at all (way of speaking, the application starts of course). Assuming my MainView is association to a MainCtrl that performs a lot of actions I do not want to do.

Comment: Regarding the server, yes I knew it, I prefer to do this on the client-side as I do not fear the hack (if someone wants to do it, it is OK).

Comment: Yes you can do it in `run` with `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function stateChangeStart(event, toState, toParams){ ... });`.  You can check `toState.name` and current time and if it is out of bounds, use `event.preventDefault();` and `$state.go` to redirect to whatever state you want.

Answer (score 5):

If I got your question right, you should do this on the server side.

On business time your webserver is responding with the "please come back later" site and during out of business your webserver could serve your site with angularJS Code.

Comment: Hello, I do not want to do this on server side, but let's say that yes, assuming I use nginx, what could be the directive please ?

Comment: I have no experience with nginx and don't know if nginx provides a predefined function for what you are looking for, but for example you could use a simple php script which checks the time and depending on the result it serves different html pages

Answer (score 0):

You could do this from angular but you'd need to get the current time from a reliable source, not the client.

Some examples of free api for time check: 
https://timezonedb.com/api 
http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html